# How to keep text in same position?

Tags: css, reactjs

In my reactjs app I have a collapse implemented but I would like to keep the text under this in the same position. I tried this css:

```
.cart{
     position: relative;
      top:70px;
}
```

This does not work, how can I keep the 'this stays here' in the same position, with for example some blurring if possible?

More code here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/XNNowM?editors=1111)

Comment: You can place an empty dummy div in place of the collapsed div when you hide it.

Comment: What do you mean in place of the collapsed div?

Comment: So you can have a hidden div of the same dimensions as the collapsed div, and show it when you collapse.

Comment: Or you can try to set the css style `visibility: hidden;` to reserve the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

working for me

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>React JS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
<p>this stays here</p>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .cart
    {
      position:relative;
    }

p {
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: and how can I make the text blurred when it is decollapsed?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your collapse component inside a div and give it some height.

```
<div style={{height: '130px'}}>
    <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
      ....   
    </Collapse>
</div>
```